# Is it possible to have screenshots of wdio allure report between steps and how to group the testcases in wdio like grouping in selenium?

Tags: report, webdriver-io, allure

I'm using allure reports to generate report for my wdio test. I'm able to capture the screenshots and add steps in the testbody under Execution.

My question is, Is it possible to group the testcases like how we do in selenium and add screenshots to each steps in the reports?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iNHs.png)

Spec file

```
it('with valid user credentials', async () =>{
    await landingScreen.tapSignIn();
    await screenShots.captureScreenShot(filePath, "OnboardingScreen.png")
    await loginScreen.waitForSignInShown();
    await screenShots.captureScreenShot(filePath, "LoginScreen.png")
    await expect(loginScreen.viewText).toBeDisplayed();
    await loginScreen.waitForUsernameTextField();
    await loginScreen.getHelpText();
    await loginScreen.getLoginText();
    await loginScreen.login(userName, password);
    await screenShots.captureScreenShot(filePath , "logincredentials.png")
    await tabs.tapAccounts();
    expectChai(await loginScreen.getLoginText()).to.equal("* Cell Number");
    await myAccounts.tapCloseIcon();
    browser.pause(2000);
    await mobileGestures.scrollUp();
    await myAccounts.tapSignout();
    await myAccounts.tapSignoutOk();
})
```

page file

```
async login(userName, password) {
    await this.spinner.waitForDisplayed({timeout:20000, reverse: true, timeoutMsg: 'Spinner is still exists' })

    try {
        await this.wait_till_screen_displayed
        allureReporter.addStep("Enter user name");
        await this.inputUserName.setValue(userName);
        allureReporter.addStep("Enter password");
        await this.inputPassword.setValue(password);
        await this.keepMeSignedIn.click();
        await this.signInButton.click();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error + "This to catch the error")
    }  
}
```

Comment: could you add the code you use to do this ?

Comment: @PDHide, I have added my part of code in the description. Could you please check it?